# cmake msys2, wrong install path for library

Tags: cmake, msys2

I'm on windows, tried to install EASTL, it got installed in Program Files instead of compiler's path.

Maybe I should change something in CMakeLists?

Library's CMakeLists: https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Commands I used:

```
cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles"
make
make install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky because MSYS2's CMake is a native Windows program that only understands Windows paths, and MSYS2 has automatic conversions of paths from POSIX-style to Windows-style that gets in the way sometimes.

These commands should work:

```
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=- cmake . -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MSYSTEM_PREFIX
make install DESTDIR=/
```